# GitHub Actions: Filter returns "jq: error Cannot iterate over null (null)"

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying out Filters in GitHub Actions, however it's returning with this error:

```
Digest: sha256:f747d8611fb26448f06a4245e252204859df6c7f81f04c248497c3e68c7740dd
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/github-actions-images/action-runner:latest
jq: error (at /github/workflow/event.json:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Here is my main.workflow:

```
workflow "New workflow" {
  on = "push"
  resolves = ["label-filter"]
}

 action "label-filter" {
  uses = "actions/bin/filter@master"
  args = "label ready"
}

 action "./github/testdeploy" {
  uses = "./github/testdeploy"
  needs = "label-filter"
}
```

Tried referencing a previous commit instead of master (actions/bin/filter@18d4c9c), however I still get the same error.

My repository is also **private**, not sure if this might have something to do with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend,

Label filters do not work with **push** events:

[GitHub's Push event][1] doesn't have `.issue.labels[].name` in its payload, as needed by the filters (https://github.com/actions/bin/blob/master/filter/bin/label#L5)